# How to debug `OverflowError: math range error` in scipy

Tags: python, r, optimization, scipy

I have the following test code which is meant to compute an MLE estimate.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def loglikelihood(params, data):
    (mu, alpha, beta) = params
    tlist = np.array(data)
    r = np.zeros(len(tlist)+1)
    for i in xrange(2,len(tlist)):
        r[i] = math.exp(-beta*(tlist[i]-tlist[i-1]))*(1+r[i-1])
    loglik  = data[-1]*mu
    loglik = loglik+alpha/beta*sum(np.exp(-beta*(tlist[-1]-tlist))-1)
    loglik = loglik+np.sum(np.log(mu+alpha*r))
    return -loglik


atimes=[58.98353497,   59.28420225,   59.71571013,   60.06750179,   61.24794134,
   61.70692463,   61.73611983,   62.28593814,   62.51691723,   63.17370423
,   63.20125152,   65.34092403,  214.24934446,  217.0390236,   312.18830525,
  319.38385604,  320.31758188,  323.50201334,  323.76801537,  323.9417007]

print minimize(loglikelihood, (0.01, 0.5,0.6), (atimes,))
```

It gives me `OverflowError: math range error` at `res = minimize(loglikelihood, (0.01, 0.5,0.6), args = (atimes,))` .

How can I fix it?

---

I am simply trying to translate the following maximum likelihood esimate (MLE) R code into python and testing it with the data I have put into atimes.

```
neg.loglik <- function(params, data, opt=TRUE) {
  mu <- params[1]
  alpha <- params[2]
  beta <- params[3]
  t <- sort(data)
  r <- rep(0,length(t))
  for(i in 2:length(t)) {
    r[i] <- exp(-beta*(t[i]-t[i-1]))*(1+r[i-1])
  }
  loglik <- -tail(t,1)*mu
  loglik <- loglik+alpha/beta*sum(exp(-beta*(tail(t,1)-t))-1)
  loglik <- loglik+sum(log(mu+alpha*r))
  if(!opt) {
    return(list(negloglik=-loglik, mu=mu, alpha=alpha, beta=beta, t=t,
                r=r))
  }
  else {
    return(-loglik)
  }
}

# insert your values for (mu, alpha, beta) in par
# insert your times for data
opt <- optim(par=c(1,2,3), fn=neg.loglik, data=data)
```

---

If tried changing the python to return loglik not -loglik. The R code must be maximizing although it is not clear to me from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html why this would be.

Now I get

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
loglik = loglik+np.sum(np.log(mu+alpha*r))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation of the R function has errors (i) 1-based vs 0-based indexing, and (ii) some sign errors.

As a result, the function is probably not bounded from below and has no minimum.
The optimizer then tries to evaluate the function for larger and larger parameter values in the direction where it decreases, and ends up putting large numbers into `math.exp` which overflows.

The overflow error does not come from scipy, but from your own function.

Comment: I tried to address the 1-based versus 0-based problems but must not have done it right. Would you mind spelling out what is wrong in more detail so I can fix it please?

Comment: Try reading each line of the R code, and compare with your own code.